Teenage son sees ghosts in basement; tries to kill his mother
I watched this years ago and I cant remember what it’s called. 

A family moves into a new house, and they had two sons and I think two daughters. 
The two sons (one teen and one middle schooler) move to the basement and share a room down there. The rest of the family stays upstairs.
Basically, the teenage son starts seeing multiple ghosts in the basement, and starts to act strange. He begins playing rock music very loudly, doesn't listen, etc. 

The only other thing I remember from the movie is that the mom went downstairs and it was kind of dark, and the teenage son chased her and tried to kill her. I remember her running from him and running up the stairs and locking him down there. If I remember correctly, he eventually broke down the basement door and the family called the cops on him. 

The Haunting in Connecticut 
Here is a trailer. 
There is also a part 2 but that sounds like the first one; I can barely remember the second.

More details posted in your answer would help you to get better votes. Links are nice but try to state what is similar in your answer to what was asked.

Im not here for votes. I just like helping people find movies, if I can.

votes aren't about popularity they are given because a good complete answer was given. You provided great links but didn't mention specifically what makes you think it is this movie. A simple line or two added such as "it matches all of your points" or  "this trailer shows the scene you referenced" it helps the OP as well as the community. Also with more points you get access to more abilities to help the community. This is a good answer and I think you are right. I just wanted to give some helpful advice to you.

Im not here much to care.  Thanks for the advice though. Much appreciated.

That you're here to genuinely help people is fine, but you'd definitely help them more by clarifying why your answer is correct, so that everyone can see that this is the searched movie.
